# Java LinkedList implementation -- deleteLast method returns tail element to be deleted but does not delete it

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

```java
public class LL {

    public Node head;
    public Node tail;
    public int size;
    public LL(){
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public void insertFirst(int value){

        Node node = new Node(value);
        node.next = head;
        head = node;

        if(tail==null){
            tail=head;
            size+=1;
        }

        size+=1;
    }
    public void insertLast(int value){
        if(tail==null) {
            insertFirst(value);
            return;
        }
        Node node = new Node(value);
        tail.next = node;
        tail = node;

        size+=1;
    }
    public void display(){
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp!=null){
            System.out.print(temp.value + " -> ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println("END");
    }
    public void insert(int value, int index){
        if(index==0){
            insertLast(value);
            return;
        }
        if(index==size){
            insertLast(value);
            return;
        }
        Node temp = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        Node node = new Node(value, temp.next);
        temp.next = node;

        size+=1;
    }
    public int deleteLast(){
        if (size<=1){
            return deleteFirst();
        }
        Node secondLast = get(size-2);
        int val = tail.value;
        tail = secondLast;
        tail.next = null;
        size-=1;
        return val;
    }

    public Node get(int index){
        Node node = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            node = node.next;
        }
        return node;
    }
    public int deleteFirst(){
        int num = head.value;
        head = head.next;
        if(head==null){
            tail=null;
        }
        size-=1;
        return num;
    }

    public class Node{
        private int value;
        private Node next;

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public Node(int value, Node next){
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LL linkedList = new LL();

        linkedList.insertLast(1);
        linkedList.insertLast(2);
        linkedList.insertLast(3);

        System.out.println("Original list:");
        linkedList.display();

        int deletedValue = linkedList.deleteLast();
        System.out.println("Deleted value: " + deletedValue);

        System.out.println("List after deleting last element:");
        linkedList.display();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to learn how to implement LinkedLists but my deleteLast() function always returns the tail element but does not take up the value of secondLast which results in no deletion.

I've checked the code with AI, and it works properly when I remove the get() method and instead iterate through the list inside the deleteLast() method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        LL linkedList = new LL();

        linkedList.insertLast(1);
        linkedList.insertLast(2);
        linkedList.insertLast(3);

        System.out.println("Original list:");
        linkedList.display();

        int deletedValue = linkedList.deleteLast();
        System.out.println("Deleted value: " + deletedValue);

        System.out.println("List after deleting last element:");
        linkedList.display();
    }
OUTPUT -------->

Original list:
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> END
Deleted value: 3
List after deleting last element:
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> END
```

Comment: "I've checked the code with AI, and it works properly when I remove the get() method and instead iterate through the list inside the deleteLast() method." This doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're saving the `tail` separately. There is no real reason to do that. It forces you to have special logic for the last element, instead of having the same logic for all elements.

Comment: It appears your "insertFirst" is broken. The first time you call `insertLast` it calls insert first and tail is null. At the end of insert first, the size will be 2 because you call size+= 1; two times.

Comment: Side note: the implementation of `deleteLast` cannot benefit from maintaining a `tail`, reason why I would not maintain it at all. Same for maintaining `size`: it just is a burden with hardly any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insertLast` method reverts to `insertFirst` for the first element. And your `insertFirst` code runs `size += 1` **twice** in certain circumstances.

Hence, when you run `get(size-2)`, size is actually 4 (even though there are 3 elements in there). You're clearing out the 'next' value of the **last** node, which was already `null`, hence why this doesn't do anything.

For the future, this isn't what Stack Overflow is for. It's not a debugging service. For next time, pepper your code with sysout statements, or more productively, learn how to use a debugger. Debugging is very simple: You go through **every relevant line** around where your error occurs and work out what values should be and what operations should do in your head. Use paper if you have to. Then run the code and check that the JVM runs things in the same way you think they should.

Had you done that you'd have figured out `size` was unexpectedly 4. You then debug *that* and eventually you'd have found this issue.